# mysql query to generate a commision report based on referred members

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

A person gets a 10% commision for purchases made by his referred friends.

There are two tables :

1. Reference table
2. Transaction table

Reference Table

```
Person_id    Referrer_id
3             1
4             1
5             1
6             2
```

Transaction Table

```
   Person_id   Amount     Action     Date
   3           100        Purchase   10-20-2011
   4           200        Purchase   10-21-2011
   6           400        Purchase   12-15-2011
   3           200        Purchase   12-30-2011
   1            50        Commision  01-01-2012
   1            10        Cm_Bonus   01-01-2012
   2            20        Commision  01-01-2012
```

How to get the following Resultset for Referrer_Person_id=1

```
Month     Ref_Pur  Earn_Comm   Todate_Earn_Comm   BonusRecvd  Paid   Due
10-2011    300      30          30                  0           0     30
11-2011      0       0          30                  0           0     30
12-2011    200      20          50                  0           0     50
01-2012      0       0          50                 10          50      0
```

Labels used above are:

```
Ref_Pur          = Total Referred Friend's Purchase for that month

Earn_Comm        = 10% Commision earned for that month

Todate_Earn_Comm = Total Running Commision earned upto that month
```

MYSQL CODE that i wrote

```
SELECT dx1.month,
       dx1.ref_pur,
       dx1.earn_comm,
       ( @cum_earn := @cum_earn + dx1.earn_comm ) as todate_earn_comm

FROM

(
    select date_format(`date`,'%Y-%m') as month,
           sum(amount) as ref_pur , 
           (sum(amount)*0.1) as earn_comm
    from transaction tr, reference rf
    where tr.person_id=rf.person_id and
          tr.action='Purchase' and
          rf.referrer_id=1
    group by date_format(`date`,'%Y-%m')
    order by date_format(`date`,'%Y-%m')

)as dx1

JOIN (select @cum_earn:=0)e;
```

How to join the query to also include BonusRecvd,Paid and Due trnsactions, which is not dependent on reference table?

and also generate row for the month '11-2011', even though no trnx occured on that month

Comment: @chris The one i tried can show ref_pur,Earn_comm,Todate_Earn_Comm but was not able to include BonusRecvd,Paid and Due.

Comment: @chris Also couldn't genrate row for the month '11-2011', since no trnx occured that month

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include commission payments and bonuses into the results, you'll probably need to include corresponding rows (`Action IN ('Commision', 'Cm_Bonus')`) into the initial dataset you are using to calculate the results on. Or, at least, that's what I would do, and it might be like this:

```
SELECT t.Amount, t.Action, t.Date
FROM Transaction t LEFT JOIN Reference r ON t.Person_id = r.Person_id
WHERE r.Referrer_id = 1 AND t.Action = 'Purchase'
   OR t.Person_id   = 1 AND t.Action IN ('Commision', 'Cm_Bonus')
```

And when calculating monthly SUMs, you can use CASE expressions to distinguish among Amounts related to differnt types of `Action`. This is how the corresponding part of the query might look like:

```
…
IFNULL(SUM(CASE Action WHEN 'Purchase'  THEN Amount END)      , 0) AS Ref_Pur,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE Action WHEN 'Purchase'  THEN Amount END) * 0.1, 0) AS Earn_Comm,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE Action WHEN 'Cm_Bonus'  THEN Amount END)      , 0) AS BonusRecvd,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE Action WHEN 'Commision' THEN Amount END)      , 0) AS Paid
…
```

When calculating the `Due` values, you can initialise another variable and use it quite similarly to `@cum_earn`, except you'll also need to subtract `Paid`, something like this:

```
(@cum_due := @cum_due + Earn_Comm - Paid) AS Due
```

One last problem seems to be missing months. To address it, I would do the following:

1. Get the first and the last date from the subset to be processed (as obtained by the query at the beginning of this post).
2. Get the corresponding month for each of the dates (i.e. another date which is merely the first of the same month).
3. Using a numbers table, generate a list of months covering the two calculated in the previous step.
4. Filter out the months that are present in the subset to be processed and use the remaining ones to add dummy transactions to the subset.

As you can see, the "subset to be processed" needs to be touched twice when performing these steps. So, for effeciency, I would insert that subset into a temporary table and use that table, instead of executing the same (sub)query several times.

A numbers table mentioned in Step #3 is a tool that I would recommend keep always handy. You would only need to initialise it once, and its uses for you may turn out numerous, if you pardon the pun. Here's but one way to populate a numbers table:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (n int);
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT 0;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
INSERT INTO numbers (n) SELECT cnt + n FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM numbers) s;
/* repeat as necessary; every repeated line doubles the number of rows */
```

And that seems to be it. I will not post a complete solution here to spare you the chance to try to use the above suggestions in your own way, in case you are keen to. But if you are struggling or just want to verify that they *can* be applied to the required effect, you can try [this SQL Fiddle page](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c8c9/35) for a complete solution "in action".